# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata while trying to generate Semantic Model

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I am trying to generate Semantic Model of a code file with below code:

```
IEnumerable<string> DefaultNamespaces =
new[]
{
    "System","System.IO","System.Net","System.Linq","System.Text","System.Text.RegularExpressions","System.Collections.Generic"
};

//string runtimePath = @"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\{0}.dll";
//var z = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.dll");

IEnumerable<MetadataReference> DefaultReferences =
    new[]
    {
       MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
    };

CSharpCompilationOptions DefaultCompilationOptions =
   new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary).WithOverflowChecks(true).WithOptimizationLevel(OptimizationLevel.Release).WithUsings(DefaultNamespaces);

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Test.dll", new SyntaxTree[] { syntaxTree }, DefaultReferences, DefaultCompilationOptions);
var result = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree, true);
```

But line :

```
IEnumerable<MetadataReference> DefaultReferences =
                        new[]
                        {
                           MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
                        };
```

is throwing exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: What .NET version?

Comment: it is .Net Framework 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Copy Local` to true in the properties for that reference in your project (if it isn't referenced, add it from NuGet).

Roslyn needs this DLL at runtime.